# Shifting from Eclipse Checkstyle to SonarQube Checkstyle

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, customization, static-analysis, checkstyle

The organization with whom I'm associated have been using IDE formatter and a similar checkstyle thing in the IDE. The file I have come up with is what a checkstyle plugin supported one, no further detail I have about it.

**Kindly Assist Me** as I want that file written/generated by *eclipse-cs plugin configuration editor* to work in **SonarQube**. The **xml file** is already in working order in Eclipse IDE but I want my Checkstyle-configuration to work in SonarQube now.

**Note:** I have already installed **checkstyle plugin 2.4** in my **SonarQube 5.4**

Comment: Don't let go of the Eclipse Checkstyle plugin - use SonarQube *in addition* to it.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the Eclipse Plugin SonarLint. Available in the Eclipse Marketplace or on their [Website](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html). Once you connect you Plugin with your SonarQube Server it will always trigger a check when you save your file.

Comment: Well I'm glad to hear from someone senior in this matter. I have understood the process you suggested me to take on. But to my problem there is a different situation where I need my SonarQube to pick my xml file. The file is not an ordinary file it is a configuration file which was written by the eclipse-cs plugin configuration editor. The auto generated file is when loaded it gives me an error. Should i show you the complete xml?